# awk/sed to compare first column and add in subsequent lines in one row

Tags: bash, row, multiple-columns

I have following contents in a file

```
20161109104500.0+0000,x,5631
20161109104500.0+0000,y,2
20161109104500.0+0000,z,2
20161109104500.0+0000,a,4117
20161109104500.0+0000,b,6182
20161109104500.0+0000,c,1556
618
225
41
4
20161109104500.0+0000,k,2689
20161109104500.0+0000,l,6182
20161109104500.0+0000,d,3241
20161109104500.0+0000,e,2418
20161109104500.0+0000,f,26
20161109104500.0+0000,g,285166.843750
20161109104500.0+0000,h,67216
```

What I would like to do is compare the fist column (date/time) and if it matches concatenate the rows into one. Following is the desired output

```
20161109104500.0+0000,x,5631,y,2,z,2,a,4117,b,6182,c,1556
20161109104500.0+0000,k,2689,l,6182,d,3241,e,2418,f,26,g,285166.843750,h,67216
```

Would like to use awk/sed to perform this operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the `awk` below will help, it will match all dates and combine them into one row and keep the non-matching.

```
awk -F',' '{if(a!=$1) {a=$1; printf "\n%s%s",$0,FS} else {a=$1;$1="";printf $0 }} END {printf "\n" }' file

20161109104500.0+0000,x,5631, y 2 z 2 a 4117 b 6182 c 1556
618,
225,
41,
4,
20161109104500.0+0000,k,2689, l 6182 d 3241 e 2418 f 26 g 285166.843750 h 67216
```

the `awk` below  will match all dates and combine them into one row and remove the non-matching.

```
awk -F, '{if(A!=$1 && A && VAL ~ /,/){print VAL;VAL=""};VAL=A==$1?VAL OFS $2 OFS $3:$0;A=$1} END{print VAL}' file

20161109104500.0+0000,x,5631 y 2 z 2 a 4117 b 6182 c 1556
20161109104500.0+0000,k,2689 l 6182 d 3241 e 2418 f 26 g 285166.843750 h 67216
```

The above code considers that the 1st fields have to match are on the basis of there next line not the whole file and assumes the file's non matching lines will not have (,) in them.

Comment: Thanks Chris, it works like a charm, except the comma separation was missing, I modified your command slightly and it works as I wanted. Thanks again                                                                               awk -F, '{if(A!=$1 && A && VAL ~ /,/){print VAL};VAL=A==$1?VAL OFS ","$2 "," OFS $3:$0;A=$1} END{print VAL}'

Comment: I am glad that it worked, please accept the answer so others can use find it.  Thanks.